# JQuery code is not executed when bootstrap-table columns displayed changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap-table which have a not visible column at start: `data-visible="false"`. The columns caption contains a button to display a modal help dialog:

```html
<script>
// This is repeated for each column that have help button, 
// some are visible at the start and some not.
$("#helpButton").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent ordering by the field 
                             // when the button is pressed.
    console.log("Hey"); // Do something
    $('#modalDialog').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

The problem is that when the user changes which columns want to see this functionality is loss. (The `console.log` is for debugging, and is confirmed that the function is not called).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are selecting by an `id`:  `$( "#helpButton" )` will only return the first matching element.

> You need to select by `class` to get all matching elements, eg.
>   `$( ".helpButton" )`.

This is why it only works for the first helpButton.

Heres an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj6b1rsL/1/)

Comment: Sorry because I wasn't clear in that point... #helpButton is in each case #helpButtonColumnA which shows the ModalHelpA, later comes the same code for #helpButtonB with his ModalHelpB, etc. So each there are all different ids.